# Can CSS variables be rounded with no SASS?

Tags: css, css-variables

I have a CSS variable which is a calculation of combined other variables, and its value happens to have decimals (147.5px to be precise). I wish I could round this up or down because I don't like decimals.

Is it possible ?

Comment: If the value is calculated, it's probably in JS, right ? Why don't you round this up in JS ?

Comment: provide a working snippet here...

Comment: @trichetriche No, the CSS calc() function can be used.

Comment: @trichetriche indeed I would like it in JS, but I can't get the value computed because my variable look like that: `--varToBeRounded: calc(var(--var1) * var(--var2) - var(--var3))`. So when I would need to get all the computed value of all the variables `--var1` `--var2` and so on, and recalculate it in JS. Too much pain...

Comment: @Bhuwan no need snippet I think, and even if I provided one, I don't have any working one because that's the whole point of my general question : can a CSS variable be rounded or not ?

Comment: @Roberrrt didn't get your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS doesn't provide any mathematical functions for rounding a numeric value, whether that value is a custom property value or some other value. `calc()` does not offer that functionality either.

Comment: As I was saying to @trichetriche above, is there a way in JS to get the computed value of a variable, and not its computed expression ? didn't find any